# Android overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.slide_out_down); not working from landscape

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I have an activity "A" that contains a recycler view, when i click on one of its items, another activity "B" is opened.

I need to close the second activity "B" with a slide to buttom animation.

For this i have created an xml file  slide_out_down.

And i have override onPause to add

overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.slide_out_down);

The problem is : 
 -A is a portrait Activity
 -B can rotate

When B is in landscape and i finish it, i don't see the animation

PS: it works fine if A and B are in portrait

Answer (score 0):

don't do it in the onPause, just do it when you are starting the activity. Order is important. By time you have onPause, you are already transitioning and it is too late.

```
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in, R.anim.out);
```

the order matters. Also can you confirm that you going from landscape to landscape? Just curious if you were attempting to animate from landscape to portrait?

Comment: im going from landscape to portrait.
i start the app in portrait, go to A and then navigate to B, rotate the device and then finish B =>no animation.

Comment: Are you overriding the pendingtransition at the exact point that you are starting the next activity?